Using the critical value from signs test to reject null hypothesis

Question 1
(a) A graduation using $20$ age groups has resulted in $6$ positive and $14$ negative deviations. Carry out the signs test on these data.
(b) A graduation covers $20$ age groups. The number of positive deviations is $6$ and the number of groups of positive deviations is $2$. Carry out the grouping of signs test using this data.

My Attempt
(a) $P\sim\text{Binomial}(20,1/2)$. The p-value is:
$$p=2\times P[P\leq 6]=2\times 0.0577=0.1154$$
This is because
\begin{align*}
P(X\leq 6)&=\binom{20}{6}0.5^6(1-0.5)^{20-6}\\
&=0.0577\\
\end{align*}
As the p-value is greater than $5\%$, there is insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis at the $5\%$ significance level.
If the number of age groups is large, we can use the approximation
$$P\sim \text{Normal}(1/2m, 1/4m)\ \square$$
(b) From the Critical Values of the Grouping of Signs Test table on pg. 189 of the Yellow Tables (Formulae and Tables for Examinations of the Faculty of Actuaries and the Institute of Actuaries, 2002), the critical value is $2$ when n$_1=6$ and $n_2=14$. I was unsure what to do next.
My Question
For (b), the solution was:

Hence, we must reject the null hypothesis at the 5% significance level and conclude there is evidence of grouping of deviations of the same age.
If $m$ is large enough $m>19$, we can use the following Normal approximation (given on pg. 34 of the Cambridge Statistical Tables).
$$G\sim N\left(\frac{n_1(n_2+1)}{n_1+n_2},\frac{(n_1n_2)^2}{(n_1+n_2)^3}\right)\ \square$$

I was unsure how the null hypothesis was rejected. If the critical value is $2$, via the Yellow Tables, what test statistic would be given to allow this? And, how would this test statistic be derived?

question (b) may have a typo: one of the "positive" may be "negative".  Since $6+2 < 20$, does this mean there were $12$ zero deviations?

I'm unsure to be honest. Would there be a way I can find out?

I'm relatively familiar with the signs test which is part (a), but not the "grouping of signs test" which is part (b). (According to here it is also called "Steven's test" https://rpubs.com/jwarby2000/896813  https://qmplus.qmul.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/4065474/mod_resource/content/1/Lecture%20PowerPoint%202023%20Week%209%2010.pdf , as well as section 3.3.6 of "MODELLING THE MORTALITY OF MEMBERS
OF GROUP SCHEMES IN SOUTH AFRICA" By JC Clur, RE Dorrington, KA Schriek and PL Lewis. From what I've read, the test statistic is the number of "groups" of positive deviations.

Here is what I think is going on based on the references I read.
Consider a sequence of "deviations":

$+ + - - + - + - + +$

There are 10 deviations, of which 6 are positive deviations, but there are 4 "groups" of positive deviations.
From what I've read, the number of groups of positive deviations is itself the test statistics for the Steven's test (grouping of signs test), which is what problem (b) is asking about (not the signs test).
So problem (b) is saying that the value of the test statistic is $G = 2$, i.e. $G$ equals the "number of groups of positive deviations".
(In particular there does not appear to be any typo in the question as written.)
Similarly the problem (b) seems to be saying that $n_1$, the number of positive deviations, is $6$, and $n_1 + n_2 = 20$ (the total number of deviations).
So they literally chose the bare minimum number of deviations required for the "rule of thumb" criterion for the normal approximation to apply (i.e. to avoid asking you to need to calculate the exact $p$ value).
The hint then seems to be saying that you can assume that the test statistic value ($G=2$, the number of groups of positive deviations) is an observation of a normally distributed random variable with mean
$$ \frac{6(14+1)}{20} = \frac{9}{2}  $$
and variance
$$ \frac{(6 \times 14)^2}{20^3} = \frac{7056}{8000} = \frac{882}{1000} $$
Presumably you can transform this into a "z-value" (i.e. for a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1) and get the threshold for a 2-sided test to have a p-value less than 5% and compare that number to $2$.

I've noted that $X\sim N(4.5,0.882)\approx 0.0445$, when $X>6$ and as this is lower than $0.05$, we can reject $H_0$? Would this be a correct way of looking at this? Also, I'm confused on where "we compare that number to $2$" and how this fits into the problem.

@Jessie I haven't done the calculations, but I agree with you if what you are saying is that $Prob( |X - 4.5| > |6 - 4.5|) \approx 0.0445$ (for a two-sided test) when $X \sim N(4.5, 0.882)$ then you could reject the null hypothesis using the decision criterion "reject the null hypothesis when the probability of an event more extreme than what occurred (measured according to a distribution approximating the true null hypothesis distribution) is less than 5%". But I think that for the "group of signs test" it sounds like the test statistic value is $2$ (there are two groups of positive deviation

and so the probability you might actually be interested in calculating is $Prob(|X-4.5| > |2-4.5|)$, although that number would be even lower because $2$ is even further from the mean $4.5$ than $6$ is an Gaussian distributions are symmetric about their means. The test statistic is "number of groups of positive deviations", and that value is $2$, so for a "hypothesis test", you assume some "null hypothesis" such that making that assumption allows you to make concrete calculations (or in this case approximations) of the distribution of the test statistic (random variable) when the null

hypothesis is true. So basically assuming the null hypothesis of the "grouping of signs test" (I guess probably that positive and negative deviations happen with equal probability although I don't know -- your textbook ideally should say) then one can calculate that the distribution of the random variable (i.e. the "test statistic") "number of groups of positive deviations" is approximately $N(4.5, 0.882)$. Then you look at the probability that something at least as extreme that the observed value of the test statistic happens.(Here the observed number of groups of positive deviations was $2$)

Anyway hypothesis tests are actually a kind of dumb decision-making procedure. (Even if they are standard in medical statistics, audit, actuarial statistics, etc.) I don't off the top of my head remember a good suggested reference for how to interpret hypothesis tests. I don't know if this'll help, but if you find a good article about "Bayes factors" (for Bayesian hypothesis testing) it should explain and compare with classical hypothesis testing, which should hopefully make the latter easier to understand. (E.g. what is the role of "test statistic", "null hypothesis", "p-value / alpha", etc.)

@Jessie In case it helps, the "test statistic" for the "signs test" is "the number of positive deviations" (observed value according to (a) was 6), while the "test statistic" for the "grouping of signs test" is "the number of groups of positive deviations" (observed value according to (b) was 2). Given a sequence of "deviations $+-++--$... , both "the number of positive deviations" and "the number of groups of positive deviations" are deterministic functions of that given sequence (also known as "statistics", i.e. values computed from observed data via a specified function / procedure).

However, the observed sequence of deviations is itself random. So a deterministic function of random observations itself has a random value, so we can also think of the statistics as random variables. (Sometimes "statistic" is used to refer to the deterministic function of the random observations, sometimes to the random variable resulting from applying that deterministic function to random observations -- think e.g. of the mean.) As random variables, they have probability distributions. In order to compute those distributions, you have to make assumptions, e.g. those of a "null hypothesis".
